# Cross-platform syncing RSS reader application

Tags: sync, rss, cross-platform

I use a number of different computers with varying OSes at home and at work.  I would like to be able to read my RSS feeds both places and have both places updated with read items, bookmarks, etc.  I would also like to avoid web-based applications; I just don't seem to get along well with any of them.  (I've tried Google Reader, Bloglines, Alesti, and News Alloy, among others, and they all have things I don't like.  Not that a native app will automatically be better.)

I suppose multiple distinct readers that all synchronize with the same source would be fine, too.  I'm most interested in Windows and MacOSX, but I would like for there to be a Linux client, too.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [FeedDemon](http://www.newsgator.com/Individuals/FeedDemon/Default.aspx) (Windows) and NetNewsWire (Mac), both sync trough Google Reader, so you don't have to use the web-interface. Both apps will do bookmarking (starring) and full read/unread syncing.

There are also clients for mobile devices which sync trough Google Reader, like NetNewsWire for the iPhone or the build-in one on the Android platform.

Haven't seen an Gnome / KDE app for Google Reader syncing.

Comment: +1, this is what I use. It also has the benefit of being able to use Google Reader if you don't have a desktop client available.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Firefox add-ons like [Feedly](http://feedly.com/), which is quite nice and can sync via Google Reader.

Comment: I don't really want a "a fun, magazine-like start page", but thanks.  I would also prefer a separate application.  Firefox is taking up too much of my memory and CPU time as it is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at [RSSOwl 2.0](http://boreal.rssowl.org/) now.  It supposedly has support for running multiple instances against a single config directory (when given the `-DmultiInstance` flag), and I'm working on a shared space to see if it can work with a high-latency config directory.  (Dropbox didn't work, unsurprisingly.)

Comment: I can't get it to work.  Remote filesystems slow it down immensely, and lack of file locking will cause it to exit.  It's obviously not meant to work this way.

Answer (score 0):

Found [Scoop](http://www.scoop.uk.com/), which is an Air application, so it works "everywhere".

I don't like its UI, though.  Maybe it will improve.